# keep some new Threads waiting ? (using Runnable)

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

i have a code like this, using Runnable :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        BigDecimal threadNumber = new BigDecimal(i);

        Runnable r = () -> {
            logger.info("thread execution started.");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            logger.info("thread execution ended.");
        };
        new Thread(r, "thread-nb-" + threadNumber).start();
    }
```

It perfectly works and starts simultanously. Console displays :

```
 2021-09-12 10:58:48,819 INFO  [thread-nb-0] com.Controller: thread execution started.
 2021-09-12 10:58:48,819 INFO  [thread-nb-1] com.Controller: thread execution started.
 2021-09-12 10:58:48,819 INFO  [thread-nb-2] com.Controller: thread execution started.
 ..
 2021-09-12 10:58:48,819 INFO  [thread-nb-18] com.Controller: thread execution started.
 2021-09-12 10:58:48,819 INFO  [thread-nb-29] com.Controller: thread execution started.
```

But, what i want to do now, is to trigger only 5 first threads at a time,
and 6th to be started once one of the 5 first ends.
How do this, keeping ***Runnable*** and ***new Thread(xxx).start();*** usage ?

thanks by advance

Comment: You can do this with *Thread Pools*. There is a really nice [Introduction to Thread Pools in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava) written by Eugen Paraschiv.

Comment: Also, you can use [a Semaphore class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). In the essence, you can set the limit of threads that can lock the semaphore (like 5) and then the rest of the threads waits for newly available limits. I don't recommend this in the production code.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Java, we rarely need to address `Thread` directly. Instead, use the Executors framework. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Here is an example where we start up an executors service with a fixed pool size. Then we enter an outer loop of cycles. For each cycle, we submit a batch of five tasks.

When the first of five tasks is nearly done, it checks a thread-safe `AtomicBoolean` to see if any of its cohorts have yet run the extra task. If not, its call to the atomic boolean sets the flag, and then we submit the extra task to the executor service.

While the extra task(s) may still be running, our outer loop moves on to start another batch of five tasks.

Lather-rinse-repeat.

```java
package work.basil.exec;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ()
    {
        // BEWARE: Messages to `System.out.println` do *NOT* appear chronologically. Always include a timestamp to study.
        System.out.println( "Demo starting. Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ". " + Instant.now() );
        final Duration sleepTime = Duration.ofSeconds( 7 );
        final int tasksCountPerCycle = 5, cycles = 2;
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( tasksCountPerCycle * 2 );
        final AtomicBoolean extraTaskHasBeenLaunched = new AtomicBoolean( false );

        final Runnable extraTask = () -> {
            System.out.println( "Starting extraTask. Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ". " + Instant.now() );
            try { Thread.sleep( sleepTime.toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            System.out.println( "Ending extraTask. Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ". " + Instant.now() );
        };

        final Callable < Void > mainTask = () -> {
            System.out.println( "Starting mainTask. Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ". " + Instant.now() );
            try { Thread.sleep( sleepTime.toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            if ( ! extraTaskHasBeenLaunched.getAndSet( true ) )
            {
                executorService.submit( extraTask );
            }
            System.out.println( "Ending mainTask. Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ". " + Instant.now() );
            return null;  // Using `Callable` in order to use `ExecutorService#invokeAll`, but have no return value.
        };

        for ( int cycle = 1 ; cycle <= ( cycles ) ; cycle++ )
        {
            System.out.println( "Launching cycle # " + cycle + ". Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ". " + Instant.now() );
            List < Callable < Void > > tasks = new ArrayList <>( tasksCountPerCycle );
            for ( int nthTask = 1 ; nthTask <= tasksCountPerCycle ; nthTask++ ) tasks.add( mainTask );
            extraTaskHasBeenLaunched.set( false );
            try { List < Future < Void > > futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        try { executorService.awaitTermination( 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.println( "Demo ending. Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ". " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

When run, we get this kind of output. **BEWARE:** Messages to `System.out.println` do *NOT* appear chronologically. Verify the actual order of events by studying a timestamp you include in your message text.

```
Demo starting. Thread ID: 1. 2021-09-13T02:27:39.943745Z
Launching cycle # 1. Thread ID: 1. 2021-09-13T02:27:39.961269Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 16. 2021-09-13T02:27:39.967115Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 18. 2021-09-13T02:27:39.967129Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 15. 2021-09-13T02:27:39.967115Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 19. 2021-09-13T02:27:39.967478Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 17. 2021-09-13T02:27:39.967181Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 15. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.969377Z
Starting extraTask. Thread ID: 21. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.969513Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 18. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.971658Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 16. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.972257Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 17. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.972518Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 19. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.972520Z
Launching cycle # 2. Thread ID: 1. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.972712Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 22. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.973142Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 23. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.973372Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 24. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.973572Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 25. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.973682Z
Starting mainTask. Thread ID: 15. 2021-09-13T02:27:46.973880Z
Ending extraTask. Thread ID: 21. 2021-09-13T02:27:53.971839Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 22. 2021-09-13T02:27:53.973773Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 25. 2021-09-13T02:27:53.973816Z
Starting extraTask. Thread ID: 18. 2021-09-13T02:27:53.973909Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 23. 2021-09-13T02:27:53.977187Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 24. 2021-09-13T02:27:53.977181Z
Ending mainTask. Thread ID: 15. 2021-09-13T02:27:53.978649Z
Ending extraTask. Thread ID: 18. 2021-09-13T02:28:00.978959Z
Demo ending. Thread ID: 1. 2021-09-13T02:28:00.979737Z
```